# Disable file downloads Selenium Firefox

Tags: selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm building a webscraping app and I'm using Selenium with a Firefox driver to open my pages. Whenever it opens a link that leads to a download, my app stalls and hangs on the link for eternity.

I've tried looking for a solution, but they never mention disabling downloads. They only talk about enabling them, changing the download directory,...

Would it be possible to detect that the link is a download link and just skip it, or maybe to skip the link whenever it opens?

Comment: Your app stalls probably because it is waiting for a page load to occur, but since it is a file download, that never happens. You could check the href attribute of the link item before clicking, in the case of file downloads it may be something like href = "!#" or href = "#" in which case you could use javascript injection to cause the click so Selenium's .Click() is not used and it won't bother waiting for a page load

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different problem and I solved it by changing Firefox capabilities.

Open `about:config` in Firefox to see list of them. Then you can pass them to webdriver through `desired_capabilities`.

```
caps = {'acceptInsecureCerts': True,
        'browserName': 'firefox',
        'marionette': True,
        'moz:firefoxOptions': {
            'args': ['--no-remote'],
            'prefs': {
                'browser.safebrowsing.downloads.enabled': False
             }
         },

driver = webdriver.Remote([...]
                desired_capabilities=caps)
```